# Is it possible to pass a function to the url field in an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to pass a function to the url field in an ajax call? I want to dynamically pass a different url to the ajax call made.

```
function getMeURL(){}

$.ajax({
  url: getMeURL,
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  }
});
```

Comment: The URL has to be a string, but you can certainly use a function that returns such a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the *result* of a function, but not a function itself as you seem to be trying to do. Here's an updated example (notice the parentheses):

```
function getMeURL() {
    return "http://www.example.com";
}
$.ajax({
  url: getMeURL(),
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't pass a function, but you can certainly pass the return value of a function.

```
url: GetMeUrl(args)
```

Answer (score 1):

use ()

```
function getMeURL(){}

$.ajax({
  url: getMeURL(),
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  }
});
```